# Handling the number of possible threads with openmp collapse

Tags: multithreading, nested, openmp

```
int DIMENSION = 4, totalPair = 0;
#pragma omp parallel for private(sx,dy,dx) 
 for(sy=0; sy<DIMENSION; sy++)
  for(sx=0; sx<DIMENSION; sx++)
   for(dy=0; dy<DIMENSION; dy++)
     for(dx=0; dx<DIMENSION;dx++){ 
    totalPair++;                                                                 
 }
```

This program returns totalPair as 256 with 16 openmp threads.
However, if I consider the collapse clause as below code, then the returned value becomes 254 with 16 threads. On the other hand, if the number of threads are 4 same as DIMENSION number, then totalPair becomes 256 which is correct.

```
int DIMENSION = 4, totalPair =0;
#pragma omp parallel for collapse(4) private(dx) 
 for(sy=0; sy<DIMENSION; sy++)
  for(sx=0; sx<DIMENSION; sx++)
   for(dy=0; dy<DIMENSION; dy++)
    for(dx=0; dx<DIMENSION;dx++){ 
    totalPair++;                                                                 
 }
```

And, even the case of below, returns totalPair as 255 with 16 threads. So, I wonder that using collapse the max allowed thread number will be equal to possible iteration count of the last loop.

```
int DIMENSION = 4, totalPair =0;
#pragma omp parallel for collapse(2) private(dy,dx) 
 for(sy=0; sy<DIMENSION; sy++)
  for(sx=0; sx<DIMENSION; sx++)
   for(dy=0; dy<DIMENSION; dy++)
    for(dx=0; dx<DIMENSION;dx++){ 
    totalPair++;                                                                 
 }
```

Comment: add `reduction(+:totalPair)` to each pragma

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually, my target is to make sure that all threads run over each value (only once with particular combination (sy = 0, sx= 0, dy=0, dx = 0), suppose allocated to thread 0) of all the loops in parallel. So, using collapse, is there any possibility to have the thread overlapped ((sy = 0, sx= 0, dy=0, dx = 0), allocated to two thread at the same time). Using reduction, I can't check in this case. But, it gives the correct answer of 256.

Comment: If you want all the threads to do the same job, don't use `for` construct. This construct distributes the iterations of a single loop among the threads, which is extended to multiple loops when using collapse` (`collapse(2)` will parallelize `sx` and `sy` dimensions only). If you want all the threads to produce `totalPair = 256` separately, then use a single `#pragma omp parallel`. In your example, your program has a race condition (the result of the loop is not deterministic), which is solved using the `reduction` directive.

Comment: Another problem arises, I found out that collapse is applicable for max 16 nested loops. Over 16 nested loops, this clause runs all the loops with 0 iteration.